# Tramp mode - file open does not work

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp

i try to access remote computer via ssh-tramp mode in emacs using this blog,
http://swizec.com/blog/cool-thing-thursday-emacs-tramp-mode/swizec/5646
Command recipe given:

```
C-x C-f //
username@
hostname
password
```

but, after i press `C-x C-f // \n username@`, it creates a new file as `username@` in the current dir.

What am i missing to activate tramp mode? i use ido mode which i disabled by pressing `C-f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to open remote files: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>`/user@host:/path/to/file`.